# How to specify a class of a field using JPA Annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a scenario where I'd like one of the fields of my EntityA be referred to by an abstract-non-persistable superclass like this:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private AbstractB upcastEntityB; // it's really a superclass for the entity which I'd like to persist

}
```

Of course hibernate complains about it with

```
references an unknown entity
```

since this class is not known to it. But I could specify that this field is to be downcast to the known EntityB type which it really is. Is there a way to do so? I really need to do this, I know this is awkward.

I suppose I could do this with xml mapping, am I right? Class can be specified in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = EntityB.class)
```

I don't understand why this would be useful though. If you know it must be and always be an EntityB, why not use EntityB as the type of the field?

Comment: Because I need to refer to this EntityB by the abstract class it extends since its really wrapped with several proxies extending that abstract class, not the entity itself. Before the field is going to be persisted I will unwrap it from all proxies to the EntityB using JPA listeners.